# Accessing the organizer profile image Eventbrite API

Tags: image, api, eventbrite, organizer

Is there a way to access the profile image for an organizer using the Eventbrite API? Thanks for any help on this subject!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is not a way to do so, but this endpoint should be available in the very near future (next month or so).